# Most Pythonic way to extract a number from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string containing a number, starting with *x*, for example, `"x270"` or `"x9"`. It always starts with *x*. I need to get the number.

I'm doing this:

```
blatz = "x22"
a1 = int(re.search("x(\d+)", blatz).group(1))
```

This doesn't seem very Pythonic. I would welcome more elegant solutions.

Comment: If it always starts with `x`: `int(blatz[1:])`?

Comment: tbh, this question is too opiniated, you have no real Problem, your code works

Comment: Hi @predicate, yes, thanks. My colleagues questioned the elegance of what I wrote, so I was looking for something different.

Comment: You have updated your code to much simpler one (Which was incidentally my answer!)

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `re` library seems to be an overkill. You don't have to search for a pattern, because you're saying that each string starts with `x`.

So you simply can do [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html):

```py
blatz = "x22"
a1 = int(blatz[1:])
```

If you need further checks, you can look at [str.startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) and/or [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

While slicing looks very pythonistic, there is also the possibility to use [other string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) that lead to the same goal:

```py
blatz = "x22"
a2 = int(blatz.lstrip("x"))  # strip "x" from the left
a3 = int(blatz.partition("x")[-1])  # get everything after "x"
a4 = int(blatz.replace("x", ""))  # replace every "x" with empty string
...
```

But slicing is faster and nothing unusual for Python programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this.

```
import re

blatz = "x22"
print(re.search("\d", blatz).group())
```